# KSQL - Relative time queries (ANSI SQL)

Tags: sql, ksqldb

How can i write a KSQL query on a bigint column that uses relative time?

I.E How can i achieve something like this....

```
SELECT timestamp,value FROM XYZ where timestamp > now() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTES
```

Where timestamp is a bigint field; milliseconds since epoch.

EDIT: Context.
I need these queries to be passed over the network/database savable and we have many queries that get the last 20mins of data from a stream on a BIGINT field.

I.E `SELECT timestamp from STREAMNAME where timestamp > 1592882020842`

The problem with saving/sending this query as more and more time elapses since the point where it was saved therefore moving further and further away from "20mins ago".

What i acutally want is a query like this.

```
SELECT timestamp from STREAMNAME where timestmap > now() - 20mins
```

No matter how many times this query is saved/loaded/sent across network/run in future. Will always return the timestamps from 20mins ago -> now

I have since found something in the documentatino that achives what i want `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` which returns the time in milliseconds in BIGINT format.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail please?
 - what is XYZ? Is it a table or a stream?
 - what are you expecting now() to return? A single immutable timestamp that is set when the query is executed, (as would be the case for a traditional db query), or the current processing time?
  - Adding an example with some input rows, the value of now() and the output would help demonstrate what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Added some context in an EDIT but have since found what i'm looking for just waiting for SRE team to upgrade KSQL to be able to use that scalar function. (UNIX_TIMESTAMP)

Comment: Great to hear. Can you please mark your question as answered then?

Comment: Your SQL examples are far from being "ANSI SQL"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP` returns the current wallclock time in milliseconds *at the time the row is processed*, i.e. it returns the processing time.  The timestamp returned by the function will advance as each row is processed.

This is different to how a traditional database would handle `now`, which would be evaluated once, and this single immutable timestamp would be used for the duration of the query, regardless of how long the query took to run.

It's important to understand the difference. If `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` does what you want... then great!

Comment: We haven't got around to using UNIX_TIMESTAMP yet; that doesn't sound like what i want i want the latter of what you mentioned where `now()` is evaluated once the query is executed for the first time.

We've just upgraded all our KSQL instances so i'm testing UNIX_TIMESTAMP soon will get back to you.

Comment: Thanks; After upgrading all our KSQLDB instances to get access to UNIX_TIMESTMAP; This is indeed what we want. Chose your answer because it clarified some things around UNIX_TIMESTAMP for me.

Comment: Anything more performant than UNIX_TIMETSTAMP for `relative` time? in KSQL? Seems like using UNIX_TIMESTAMP on some of our streams basically crashes KSQL because i guess its running that check on every row on like our 1million+ rows

Comment: Hi Shanon, I'm not sure what you mean.  Using UNIX_TIMESTAMP certainly shouldn't crash ksqlDB.  Yes, this function is called each time a row is processed, but it is not an expensive call.  You'd need to provide more info for me to help more.

Comment: More investigation was needed; we just had many problems with KSQL we ended up pulling the plug and just reading from the raw topic; maybe we were just doing things wrong but it seemed very unperformant / constantly breaking. Maybe you can help with our kafka problems though haha, do you have any good kafka communitys i can join to ask questions? We're rebuilding the national grid infrastructure system here in my home country

Comment: Sorry to hear you had problems with ksql. SO or the Confluent community slack (https://launchpass.com/confluentcommunity), are probably the two best ways to ask questions about Kafka.